# How do I suppress a CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF warning on a per file basis in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

How do I suppress a `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF` warning on a per file basis in Xcode?

I would like to to suppress some warnings using the per-file option Compile Sources in Xcode.

I've tried:

```
-Wno-CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF
-fno-CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF
```

I've usually done this kind of suppression with a pragma directive.

(PS I don't need to be told that this isn't a good thing to be doing.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, for the benefit of others, it's `-Wno-implicit-retain-self`

I should have realised this. The corresponding flag should have been used,, which I found [here](http://samdmarshall.com/blog/buildsettings.html)